# Apply material-ui overrides only in mobile view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material-UI in react. Is there a way to only add the overrides from theme provider in mobile view? I'm using the  component and I would like to remove the boxShadow of the component if it is in mobile view.

this is the snippet of my code:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';

return (
  <Card>
    <CardContent>
      Sample content here
    </CardContent>
  </Card>
);
```

and from my theme

```
MuiCard: {
  root: {
    boxShadow: 'none'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course.
You could use `[theme.breakpoints.up("md")]` or `theme.breakpoints.down("sm")`

In your case it will be like this:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = theme => ({
   customCard: {
      [theme.breakpoints.down("sm")]: {
            boxShadow: "none",
        },
   }
});

function SomeComponent({classes}) {

return (<Card className={classes.customCard}>
            <CardContent>
              Sample content here
            </CardContent>   
       </Card> );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(SomeComponent);
```